# Router in Angular web app does not work on same component

Tags: angular, url, angular8

I have a problem with angular router.

Currently I'm in my router `/HOME` and I'd like to route from a button from there to `/HOME#id=123456`

How can I do that? I'm trying something like:

```
<a class="app-card bg-petrol"[routerLink]="['/HOME']" [queryParams]="{'id':'123456'}">
```

But nothing happen - even nothing in the console.

*edit: added routes file*

**app.routes.ts**

```
{
  path: Routes.HOME,
  loadChildren: () => import('../routes/home/home.module').then(m => m.HomeModule),
  data: { hideNavSearch: true },
},
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use queryparams with the link. For example :

```
<a [routerLink]="['HOME ']"  [queryParams]="{'id':'123456'}">
```

Answer (score 0):

In Angular, you need to define a parameterized path if there you want Angular to route to it. Add a new path in `app.routing.module.ts` with same name but having a parameter id.

`app.routing.module.ts`

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ ... ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([ 
      { path: 'HOME', component: HomeViewComponent }, 
      { path: 'HOME/:id', redirectTo: 'HomeViewComponent' } // add new route with id parameter
    ])
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule,
  ],
  providers: [],

})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

After that call your page like this:

```
<a routerLink="/HOME"  [queryParams]="{'id':'123456'}">
```

This will resolve your problem.

Comment: I've added my routing file, looks very different, how should I add the params?

Comment: Can you create a small stackblitz demo. It would be much more clear. Also, please add complete routing file with ony HOME route, as it will be enough to provide proper answer.